# How to make player jump to mouse position

Tags: 3d, mmo, godot

Currently I have the player moving towards the mouse position , using this example :

https://kidscancode.org/godot_recipes/3d/click_to_move/

now how would I achieve jumping to the mouse position, currently my script is like this:

```
  void Player::move(const float &delta) {
            velocity.y += gravity * delta;
    
            if (target != godot::Vector3::ZERO) {
    
                look_at(target, godot::Vector3::UP);
                rotate_x(0.0);
                velocity = -get_transform().basis.z * speed;
    
                auto distance_to_target = get_transform().origin.distance_to(target);
                if (distance_to_target < 0.5) {
                    velocity = target = godot::Vector3::ZERO;
                }
    
// weird behavior not what I'm looking for

                if (godot::Input::get_singleton()->is_action_pressed("Jump") && is_on_floor()) {
                    godot::Godot::print(std::to_string(distance_to_target).c_str());
                    velocity.y = 100;
                }
            }
    
            velocity = move_and_slide(velocity, godot::Vector3::UP);
        }
```

I tried messing around with velocity.y , but it always result in weird behaviors and the player when landing point/look at the floor.

how would I do it correctly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the version in the article, I'll work from it:

```
extends KinematicBody

export var speed = 5
export var gravity = -5

var target = null
var velocity = Vector3.ZERO

func _physics_process(delta):
    velocity.y += gravity * delta
    if target:
        look_at(target, Vector3.UP)
        rotation.x = 0
        velocity = -transform.basis.z * speed
        if transform.origin.distance_to(target) < .5:
            target = null
            velocity = Vector3.ZERO
    velocity = move_and_slide(velocity, Vector3.UP)
```

---

I suggest (against what the linked article says) to check the distance to the target instead of checking with `ZERO` (`ZERO` could be a valid target). And, I'll set `target` to `transform.origin` for initialization. Since we are already checking for the distance, refactor the conditional that does that:

```
extends KinematicBody

export var speed = 5
export var gravity = -5

var target = transform.origin
var velocity = Vector3.ZERO

func _physics_process(delta):
    velocity.y += gravity * delta
    if transform.origin.distance_to(target) < 0.5:
        # perhaps you want to flip this line
        target = transform.origin
        velocity = Vector3.ZERO
    else:
        look_at(target, Vector3.UP)
        rotation.x = 0
        velocity = -transform.basis.z * speed

    velocity = move_and_slide(velocity, Vector3.UP)
```

---

There is another problem with the article code: when we write `velocity` we are erasing the vertical velocity we set with gravity (which, of course, you would not notice until the physics object is not on the floor). So let us fix that:

```
extends KinematicBody

export var speed = 5
export var gravity = -5

var target = transform.origin
var velocity = Vector3.ZERO

func _physics_process(delta):
    velocity.y += gravity * delta
    if transform.origin.distance_to(target) < 0.5:
        # perhaps you want to flip this line
        target = transform.origin
        velocity = Vector3(0, velocity.y, 0)
    else:
        look_at(target, Vector3.UP)
        rotation.x = 0
        var vel = -transform.basis.z * speed
        velocity = Vector3(vel.x, velocity.y, vel.z)

    velocity = move_and_slide(velocity, Vector3.UP)
```

---

Now, let us work on the jump. First of all, do not use `is_on_floor` before using `move_and_slide`. Let us try at the end:

```
extends KinematicBody

export var speed = 5
export var gravity = -5

var target = transform.origin
var velocity = Vector3.ZERO

func _physics_process(delta):
    velocity.y += gravity * delta
    if transform.origin.distance_to(target) < 0.5:
        # perhaps you want to flip this line, maybe just set x and z
        target = transform.origin
        velocity = Vector3(0, velocity.y, 0)
    else:
        look_at(target, Vector3.UP)
        rotation.x = 0
        var vel = -transform.basis.z * speed
        velocity = Vector3(vel.x, velocity.y, vel.z)

    velocity = move_and_slide(velocity, Vector3.UP)
    if is_on_floor() and Input.is_action_pressed("Jump"):
        velocity.y = 10
```

Did you see that? We have a fixed jump velocity, it might undershoot. Or it might overshoot which is worse because the code snaps to the target horizontal position mid-air.

So that snapping must only happen when `is_on_floor()` is true. Which means we need to put `move_and_slide` before all that:

```
extends KinematicBody

export var speed = 5
export var gravity = -5

var target = transform.origin
var velocity = Vector3.ZERO

func _physics_process(delta):
    velocity.y += gravity * delta
    velocity = move_and_slide(velocity, Vector3.UP)
    if is_on_floor():
        if Input.is_action_pressed("Jump"):
            velocity.y = 10
        if transform.origin.distance_to(target) < 0.5:
            # perhaps you want to flip this line, maybe just set x and z
            target = transform.origin
            velocity = Vector3(0, velocity.y, 0)
        else:
            look_at(target, Vector3.UP)
            rotation.x = 0
            var vel = -transform.basis.z * speed
            velocity = Vector3(vel.x, velocity.y, vel.z)
```

Now it jumps, falls to the ground, then it adjusts directions.

Perhaps you want it to compute how much to jump to get there. With the help of good old motion equations we can do that. We will need the horizontal distance. It is also a good idea to check against horizontal distance, just in case the target is on a different elevation.

And there you go, this code jumps to the target:

```
extends KinematicBody

export var speed = 5
export var gravity = -5

var target = transform.origin
var velocity = Vector3.ZERO

func _physics_process(delta):
    velocity.y += gravity * delta
    velocity = move_and_slide(velocity, Vector3.UP)
    if is_on_floor():
        var h_distance = Vector2(transform.origin.x, transform.origin.z).distance_to(Vector2(target.x, target.z))
        if Input.is_action_pressed("Jump"):
            var expected_time = h_distance / speed
            var v_velocity = -0.5 * expected_time * gravity
            velocity.y = v_velocity
        if h_distance < 0.5:
            # perhaps you want to flip this line, maybe just set x and z
            target = transform.origin
            velocity = Vector3(0, velocity.y, 0)
        else:
            look_at(target, Vector3.UP)
            rotation.x = 0
            var vel = -transform.basis.z * speed
            velocity = Vector3(vel.x, velocity.y, vel.z)
```

*By the way, if you change the target mid-air, it will complete the jump, then change direction and go. Similarly, if it fails to land on the target because of an obstacle, it will change direction after landing then go. There is no path-finding or obstacle avoidance (other than sliding on walls because `move_and_slide`) of course.*

If this is not the behavior that you want, hopefully you can modify it from there. Remember:

- When setting `velocity` you are overriding `velocity.y`
- Use `is_on_floor` after `move_and_slide` (and `move_and_slide` after applying gravity). *The `KinematicBody` might be on the floor, but if it didn't slide on it, it will not register.*
- Consider if you want it to be able to change direction mid-air or not. *If the target is directly below it will suddenly stop the jump arc and fall vertically.*
- Do not assume that `ZERO` is not a valid target.

I'm letting translating that to C++ to you, because, honestly, it is too much setup to test it (I'm being lazy), and I'm not confident to get it right without testing it. Yet you should be able to do it with little effort.

---

**Note**: The value `0.5` on `h_distance < 0.5` might be too large depending on the size of the scene. Which results in the motion stopping too short. If that happens, try an smaller value.

---

### Addendum: Making jump time constant

Look again at this code:

```
var expected_time = h_distance / speed
var v_velocity = -0.5 * expected_time * gravity
velocity.y = v_velocity
```

It only sets the vertical velocity, and uses the `speed` it has. If you want the jump to take a constant time, you would have to change the speed. Solve the equation for speed:

```
var expected_time = h_distance / speed
=>
speed * expected_time = h_distance
=>
speed = h_distance / expected_time
```

It also means you would have to do the following again:

```
look_at(target, Vector3.UP)
rotation.x = 0
var vel = -transform.basis.z * speed
velocity = Vector3(vel.x, velocity.y, vel.z)
```

Thus:

```
var jump_speed = h_distance / jump_time
var v_velocity = -0.5 * jump_time * gravity
look_at(target, Vector3.UP)
rotation.x = 0
var vel = -transform.basis.z * jump_speed
velocity = Vector3(vel.x, v_velocity, vel.z)
```

And put `jump_time` (it is in seconds, by the way) as an exported variable alongside `speed`. That should do it… Well, almost. The last block will undo it by setting the velocity again. We can simply put the second if statement in the else of the first one. However, as you have seen we have some code repetition. Instead, I suggest the following refactor:

```
if is_on_floor():
    var h_distance = Vector2(transform.origin.x, transform.origin.z).distance_to(Vector2(target.x, target.z))
    var h_velocity = speed
    var v_velocity = 0
    if Input.is_action_pressed("Jump"):
        h_velocity = h_distance / jump_time
        v_velocity = -0.5 * jump_time * gravity
    if h_distance < 0.05:
        # perhaps you want to flip this line, maybe just set x and z
        target = transform.origin
        velocity = Vector3(0, v_velocity, 0)
    else:
        look_at(target, Vector3.UP)
        rotation.x = 0
        var vel = -transform.basis.z * h_velocity
        velocity = Vector3(vel.x, v_velocity, vel.z)
```

---

### Addendum: Fixing both time and jump height

A way to make the object reach higher is by increasing the initial vertical velocity. However, the object will also take longer to fall down. Thus, we need to change the rate at which the object falls down, which means tweaking the gravitational acceleration.

As soon as the object begins it upwards motion, its vertical velocity begins to decrease according to the gravitational acceleration. Eventually it reaches a point where the vertical velocity is zero. At which point it cannot continue to move up. Thus, that is the highest point of the jump.

The rate at which the object lost its upwards velocity, is the same rate at which it gains downwards velocity: the gravitational acceleration. Since it is the same rate, it takes the same time for the object to get to highest than it gets to fall down from it.

Thus, we can consider the motion in two halves. For the second half, the initial velocity is zero and the object accelerates down for half the jump time. The final velocity has the same magnitud as the initial velocity of the jump, but in the opposite direction. Thus: `v_velocity = -0.5 * jump_time * gravity`, which is what we were using before.

*Remember that gravity is a negative value.*

Now, how high the object gets depends on its initial velocity and the gravitational acceleration. Which are related by the jump time as shown above.

And I'm not going to bother finding the specific equation. Instead, I'll pick a general one:

```
y = v_velocity * time + 0.5 * gravity * time * time
```

We can figure out how high the object is at half way into the jump by replacing `time` with `0.5 * jump_time`:

```
jump_height = v_velocity * (0.5 * jump_time) + 0.5 * gravity * (0.5 * jump_time) * (0.5 * jump_time)

=>

jump_height = v_velocity * 0.5 * jump_time + 0.5 * gravity * 0.25 * jump_time * jump_time

=>

jump_height = v_velocity * 0.5 * jump_time + 0.125 * gravity * jump_time * jump_time
```

We can replace `v_velocity` by the formula we had before:

```
jump_height = (-0.5 * jump_time * gravity) * 0.5 * jump_time + 0.125 * gravity * jump_time * jump_time
```

And we got to solve for `gravity`:

```
jump_height = -0.25 * gravity * jump_time * jump_time + 0.125 * gravity * jump_time * jump_time

=>

jump_height = (-0.25 + 0.125) * gravity * jump_time * jump_time

=>

jump_height = -0.125 * gravity * jump_time * jump_time

=>

-0.125 * gravity * jump_time * jump_time = jump_height

=>

gravity * jump_time * jump_time = (1/-0.125) * jump_height

=>

gravity * jump_time * jump_time = -8 * jump_height

=>

gravity = -8 * jump_height / (jump_time * jump_time)
```

And thus we can update the code:

```
func _physics_process(delta):
    velocity.y += gravity * delta
    velocity = move_and_slide(velocity, Vector3.UP)
    if is_on_floor():
        var h_distance = Vector2(transform.origin.x, transform.origin.z).distance_to(Vector2(target.x, target.z))
        var h_velocity = speed
        var v_velocity = 0
        if Input.is_action_pressed("Jump"):
            h_velocity = h_distance / jump_time
            gravity = -8 * jump_height / (jump_time * jump_time)
            v_velocity = -0.5 * jump_time * gravity
        if h_distance < 0.05:
            # perhaps you want to flip this line, maybe just set x and z
            target = transform.origin
            velocity = Vector3(0, v_velocity, 0)
        else:
            look_at(target, Vector3.UP)
            rotation.x = 0
            var vel = -transform.basis.z * h_velocity
            velocity = Vector3(vel.x, v_velocity, vel.z)
```

And yes, that means that each jump will have a different gravity.

---

### Addendum: Thank you Mario, but the floor is in another elevation

So far we have been ignoring the vertical component of the `target` (when we compute the horizontal distance - `h_distance` - we only use `target.x` and `target.z`).

As a consequence, if the target is above, the jump will not be able to complete the parabola, and thus will end up short of the target (we found floor before we expected it). Similarly, if the target is below, the jump parabola will overextend, and thus will overshoot the target (the floor wasn't were we expected it, so the jump arc kept going).

Alright, so what do we know? We know that after `jump_time`, we should have reached target coordinates:

```
position(time = jump_time) = (target.x, target.y, target.z)
```

To make it easier, I'll call the initial coordinate zero, and we will be working on jump arc as if it were 2D. Our dimensions are `h` and `v`:

```
position(time = 0) = (0, 0)
position(time = jump_time) = (h_distance, v_distance)
```

Where:

```
h_distance = Vector2(transform.origin.x, transform.origin.z).distance_to(Vector2(target.x, target.z))
v_distance = target.y - transform.origin.y
```

*The sign of `v_distance` is important.*

We also know that the motion will follow the motion equations. This is the one we had previously:

```
y = v_velocity * time + 0.5 * gravity * time * time
```

Which I will rename to `v` for vertical:

```
v(time) = v_velocity * time + 0.5 * gravity * time * time
```

Let me restate the points we had before:

```
v(time) = v_velocity * time + 0.5 * gravity * time * time

v(0) = 0
v(jump_time) = v_distance
```

Actually `v(0) = 0` is trivial, we can see that evaluating `v(time)` when `time = 0` will gives us `0`. Let us not worry about that one:

```
v(time) = v_velocity * time + 0.5 * gravity * time * time
v(jump_time) = v_distance
```

And this gives us - *drum roll* - infinite solutions. There are infinite possible jump arcs that satisfy those equations. The jump arc could go higher, and have higher gravity, or go lower but with less gravity.

We dealt with that before. We will be modifying `gravity` based on the `jump_height`. However, we want to make sure the jump always goes above both start and end points. If it were below, we would end with negative gravity, and we don't want that.

So, I'll say that `height = max(v_distance, 0) + jump_height` where `jump_height > 0`.

Thus, let us have it like this:

```
v(time) = v_velocity * time + 0.5 * gravity * time * time
v(jump_time/2) = height
v(jump_time) = v_distance
```

By the way, to keep these equations short, I will be using:

```
tt = jump_time * jump_time
gtt = gravity * jump_time * jump_time
```

Now let us solve the equation system. Starting with:

```
v(jump_time) = v_distance
```

We have:

```
v_distance = v(jump_time) = v_velocity * jump_time + 0.5 * gtt

=>

v_distance = v_velocity * jump_time + 0.5 * gtt

=>

v_distance - 0.5 * gtt = v_velocity * jump_time

=>

(v_distance - 0.5 * gtt)/jump_time = v_velocity
```

And starting with:

```
v(jump_time/2) = height
```

We have:

```
height = v(jump_time/2) = v_velocity * jump_time/2 + 0.5 * gtt/4

=>

height = v_velocity * 0.5 * jump_time + 0.125 * gtt

=>

height - 0.125 * gtt = v_velocity * 0.5 * jump_time

=>

(height - 0.125 * gtt) / (0.5 * jump_time) = v_velocity
```

Thus:

```
v_velocity
= (height - 0.125 * gtt) / (0.5 * jump_time)
= (v_distance - 0.5 * gtt)/jump_time

=>

height * 2.0 - 0.125 * gtt * 2.0 = v_distance - 0.5 * gtt

=>

height * 2.0 - 0.25 * gtt = v_distance - 0.5 * gtt

=>

height * 2.0 = v_distance - 0.5 * gtt + 0.25 * gtt

=>

height * 2.0 = v_distance - 0.25 * gtt

=>

height * 2.0 + 0.25 * gtt = v_distance

=>

0.25 * gtt = v_distance - height * 2.0

=>

gtt = (v_distance - height * 2.0) / 0.25

=>

gtt = v_distance/0.25 - height * 2.0/0.25

=>

gtt = 4 * v_distance - 8 * height

=>

gravity * tt = 4 * v_distance - 8 * height

=>

gravity = (4 * v_distance - 8 * height)/tt
```

And we replace that here:

```
(v_distance - 0.5 * gtt)/jump_time = v_velocity
```

Getting:

```
v_velocity = (v_distance - 0.5 * ((4 * v_distance - 8 * height)/tt) * tt)/jump_time 

=>

v_velocity = (v_distance - 0.5 * (4 * v_distance - 8 * height))/jump_time

=>

v_velocity = (v_distance - (2 * v_distance - 4 * height))/jump_time

=>

v_velocity = (v_distance - 2 * v_distance + 4 * height)/jump_time

=>

v_velocity =  (4 * height - v_distance)/jump_time
```

Alright, update the code:

```
func _physics_process(delta):
    velocity.y += gravity * delta
    velocity = move_and_slide(velocity, Vector3.UP)
    if is_on_floor():
        var h_distance = Vector2(transform.origin.x, transform.origin.z).distance_to(Vector2(target.x, target.z))
        var v_distance = target.y - transform.origin.y
        var h_velocity = speed
        var v_velocity = 0
        if Input.is_action_pressed("Jump"):
            var height = max(v_distance, 0) + jump_height
            gravity = (4 * v_distance - 8 * height) / (jump_time * jump_time)
            h_velocity = h_distance / jump_time
            v_velocity = (4 * height - v_distance) / jump_time
        if h_distance < 0.05:
            # perhaps you want to flip this line, maybe just set x and z
            target = transform.origin
            velocity = Vector3(0, v_velocity, 0)
        else:
            look_at(target, Vector3.UP)
            rotation.x = 0
            var vel = -transform.basis.z * h_velocity
            velocity = Vector3(vel.x, v_velocity, vel.z)
```

*Tested.*

Comment: thank you very very much, for this detailed and amazing answer, I have implemented it in C++ , but there is an issue , I feel like the player is jumping half the distance, and when jumping diagonally , the `y` becomes higher, that the play jump up high, I have added a link to let you see how it behaves : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cnFUi7weKnU   , maybe you can spot what is wrong, thank you again.

Comment: @Abanoub what I notice is the following: 1. You are using `global_transform`, does not seem to be the source of the problem (I tested with `global_transform` in GDScript and it isn't a problem). 2. `rotate_x(0)` and `rotation.x = 0` is not the same (at least in GDScript, `rotate_x(0)` does nothing). 3. It is not sliding, it should be moving on the ground until it reaches the destination. Now, it could be jumping less if the `KinematicBody` is scaled down. But then it would slide to the target. Its as if the the target is wrong. I suggest to make a marker for the target, to discard.

Comment: @Abanoub Something else: enable Visible Collision Shapes in the Debug menu. I'm wondering if it is not sliding because something is wrong with the collision shape.

Comment: sorry for the late reply , the player actually move correctly , but when jumping , the diagonal jump seem right , but the near jump , it's like half the distance , I have updated the code to be exact replica of your code , but in C++ ,  please take a look :-  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ysAGjBZ3gs

Comment: @Abanoub I can only assume that the cause of the problem is elsewhere. It still looks to me like the target is wrong.

Comment: here is some debug info : https://pastebin.com/i3d4rHqh , or how do you want me to share it with you so you can take a look at it when you have some time?

Comment: @Abanoub I'm convinced it reaches the coordinates set in the target, I not so sure the target is placed where it should. About you sharing it, I don't know, it is your project.

Comment: @Abanoub how about you flip that line I was saying in the comments of the code of the answer? Wrote as I had it, it snaps the target to its own position. Flipped, it snaps its own position to the target. See if it teleports.

Comment: I have flipped it , I can share it with you on github, if you want!

Comment: @Abanoub That is up to you. It is your project and you need to decide if want to share it. Also, I can't guarantee I will find the source of the problem.

Comment: well, I will consider , your answer as the accepted answer , as it has fixed 90% of the issue I was facing , what is your github account I will share it no problem.

Comment: @Abanoub https://github.com/theraot

Comment: I have added you to the repo, also a question , if the camera rotated `-30` on the `x` , would that change the behaviour ?

Comment: @Abanoub I had a look at the code, nothing I saw that would be clearly wrong. I don't think changing the camera would change the behavior. By the way, I haven't managed to run the code, scons makes a lib, and godot wants a dll (I'm on windows). Will look into that later.

Comment: well I have made a `GDScript` version , so it is easier for you when you have time to check it : https://github.com/AbanoubNassem/game

Comment: @Abanoub That did help, much easier to debug when I can run the code. The issue is the size of things. In `h_distance < 0.5` that `0.5` is too much for the dimension you are using, so it is considering close enough a noticeable distance, and thus ends up moving short. `0.05` works much better for your scene.

Comment: what is the correct way to add the animation time to the Jump, so the animation start and end with the jump , I'm currently doing : https://pastebin.com/jqv0GszP , but it seems off

Comment: @Abanoub `expected_time` is… Time. It is how much time we expect the jump to take given the speed and distance it has to jump. Instead you want to specify time and figure out the speed based on that and the distance it has to jump. Which is what I did on the code under "Addendum: Making jump time constant", use that. Now, `animation_player->get_animation("Jump")->get_length()` will give you time in seconds. Thus, you should be able to use that in place of `jump_time` directly. I remind you to go back to physics equations: speed is distance over time.

Comment: appreciate it, thank you very much 

Comment: sorry one more thing,  what if I want to jump over an object , how to consider the `mouse` position or the `object` height?

Comment: @Abanoub Added a version that lets you specify the height of the jump under "Addendum: Fixing both time and jump height".

Comment: I have updated the repo with the new instructions you gave me , but now when I jump over a static body then jump off it , the characters seems going of the (track)position, but then snaps back to it , is there a way to fix that so it goes directly to the target position ? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sFkqbD_Lx1E

Comment: @Abanoub extended answer.

Comment: thank you again , but there is a slight problem , the player changes direction when lands , any clue what is the cause of that?

Comment: @Abanoub I guess it is not accurate enough and overshoots ever so slightly. Perhaps a matter of tweaking that `0.05` again. The other thing that comes to mind is to switch to least Semi-implicit Euler. I haven't tried that with Godot, if you want to try, I think it would be like this: `velocity = move_and_slide(Vector3(velocity.x, velocity.y + gravity * delta * 0.5, velocity.z), Vector3.UP); velocity.y += gravity * delta`, it is trying to compensate for the motion not being aware of the acceleration.

Comment: changing `0.05` back to `0.5` , did the trick it's perfect now , thanks alot for your time and help 

Comment: hey, sorry I have found a bug, jumping over an object then go down, multiple times making the jump go higher , like there is no max height I believe , I have updated the repo please take a look when you have time : https://github.com/AbanoubNassem/game , maybe am doing something wrong!

Comment: @Abanoub You can see here: https://github.com/AbanoubNassem/game/blob/d422b076cb67c67ff12163ed9ed96d6b6585e67c/scripts/Hero.gd#L26 that you first compute `jump_height` from `jump_time` and `gravity`. Then you compute `height` from it. And then you compute `gravity` from `height`. The next jump, it would compute `jump_height` with the new gravity, and so on. As a result, it has less gravity each jump. Don't do that. You fix the value of `gravity` and compute `jump_height` from it. Or you either fix the value of `jump_height` and compute `gravity` based on it, which I believe is what you want.